# Multi-element xml query to variable

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

my xml looks like this:

```
        <root>
            <x a1 = "abc">
                <y a2 = "def"> 
                    <z value1 = 5 value2 = 10 value3 = 15/>             
                </y>
            </x>
        </root>
```

my main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int value;
    IEnumerable<XElement> xs = from x in xDoc.Descendants("x")
                               where (string)x.Attribute("a1") == "abc"
                               select x;
    IEnumerable<XElement> ys = from y in xs.Descendants("y")
                               where (string)y.Attribute("a2") == "def"
                               select time;
    IEnumerable<XElement> zs = from z in ys.Descendants("z")
                               where z.Attribute == value1
                               select z;
}
```

I am trying to set int value to value 1, 2 or 3 of node z depending on a certain condition. My problem occurs when i try to filter the required value in node z. could someone explain how I could assign the matching value of node z to int value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select some element of z node:

```
string value = "value1";

var query = xDoc.Descendants("x")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("a1") == "abc")
                .Descendants("y")
                .Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("a2") == "def")
                .Descendants("z")
                .Select(z => (string)z.Element(value))
                .Select(s => Int32.Parse(s.Replace("\"", "")));
```

Result of query - `IEnumerable<int>`. You can apply `Single` of `First` if you sure that there will be one value, or you need first one.

Also I don't understand why you keep values as `"5"` instead of simple `5`.

Comment: I think this will do it, except I don't understand for the last line. Could you please explain it, thanks!

Comment: @JeliBeanMachine sure, your value elements has text in double quotes, which cannot be parsed as integer. So, I remove double quotes and then do parsing.

Comment: I understand the parsing, it's the .Select(s => and s.Replace("\""," "))) part that's confusing me. What is s? and what does .Replace do? would this assign the value to a variable int value = s?

Comment: @JeliBeanMachine `s.Replace("\""," ")` makes string `5` from string `"5"` - removes double quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help with xml! I think I'm done using it for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath (System.Xml.XPath)  here

```
var elemZ = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//x[@a1='abc']/y[@a2='def']/z");

int val1 = (int)elemZ.Attribute("value1");
```

after correcting your xml as  `<z value1 = "5" value2 = "10" value3 = "15" />`

You can even get all attribute values by a single linq

```
var values = elemZ.Attributes().Select(a => (int)a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
 IEnumerable<XElement> z's = from z in y.Descendants("z")
                                  where z.Attribute("value1") != null
                                  select z;
```